# Command line parameters c++

Tags: c++, parameters, command, line

I have been asked to create a c++ program that "accepts a command line parameter and outputs the number of prime numbers less than this value; if no parameter is given, output just `std::endl` to `std::cout`"

I understand how to look up prime numbers but I am unsure what a "command line parameter" is and how it ties into the work. Also, I think if there is no parameter given, you just `std::cout << std::endl`?

I have tried to work out what a command line parameter is but cannot find any meaningful resources to this effect.