# C++ getting a "second command-line parameter"

Tags: c++, unix

I am working on an assignment which follows this criteria:

Task:

A "perfect" number is an integer that is equal to the sum of its divisors
(where 1 is considered a divisor). For example, 6 is perfect because its
divisors are 1, 2, and 3, and 1 + 2 + 3 is 6. Similarly, 28 is perfect because
it equals 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14.
A "quite good" number is an integer whose "badness" – the size of the
difference between the sum of its divisors and the number itself – is not
greater than a specified value. For example, if the maximum badness is set at
3, there are 12 "quite good" numbers less than 100: 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 16, 18,
20, 28, 32, and 64;
Your task is to write a C++ program, quitegood, that determines
numbers of a specified maximum badness that are less than a specified value. The limiting value
and maximum badness are specified as command-line arguments when the program is executed.

The first question asked the following:

Begin by writing a program that prints perfect numbers (badness 0) up to values less than
10000, separated by a single space. For example quitegood 100 should print 6 28.

Which I have done here:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   int candidate = 0;
   int badness;
    for(int i=2; i<10000; i++)
    { //Start for loop 1

        for (int j = 1; j<i; j++)
        { //Start for loop 2
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                  candidate += j;

            }


        } //End for loop 2

        if(candidate %i ==0)
        { //Start of if 1
        cout << i << endl;
        } //End of if 1


            candidate = 0;


    } // End of loop 1
    return 0;
}
```

But the second question asks:

Extend the program so that the badness limit can be specified as a second command-line parameter. For example quitegood 100 3 will print 2 3 4 6 8 10 16 18 20
28 32 64.

The question is, how do I go about receiving a "second command-line parameter" for use in my code?

NOTE: We are required to test our codes on a Unix terminal (cygwin) against an automated marking system, if that helps at all.

Hope this is sufficient information, sorry if it isn't this is all very confusing,
Thank you.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html To parse the command line options and/or arguments or you could use std::cin to set parameters.

Comment: You will need to use `argc` and `argv` arguments. Didn't your teacher tell you about that before giving you the assignment?

Comment: `argc` contains the number of parameters that are inside the `char*` array `argv`. So if `argc>2`, you can access your extra parameter with `argv[2]`. `argv[0]` is always present and represents the program name (usually the path to the executable).

Comment: That's a lot of details just to ask about command line parameters. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813321/command-line-parameters-c

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272550/c-command-line-parameters/51534733#51534733

Comment: The `argc` parameter will hold the count of arguments passed and `argv` holds the list of arguments. You would have to use them to check if more than one parameter is passed and the contents of it.

Comment: You haven't correctly solved the first part of the assignment yet. Never mind a second command-line argument, where's your first! Seems like you hardcoded an upper limit of 10,000 but that is supposed to be the maximum value for a command-line argument that you're not taking in at present.

Comment: @hetepeperfan std::cin cannot be used to retrieve input in the manner specified in the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int n = 10000;
    int badnessLimit = 0;

    if (argc > 1) {
        istringstream nArg(argv[1]);
        if (!(nArg >> n) || !nArg.eof()) {
            cerr << "Invalid first argument\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        istringstream badnessArg(argv[2]);
        if (!(badnessArg>> badnessLimit) || !badnessArg.eof()) {
            cerr << "Invalid second argument\n";
            return 2;
        }
    }
    cout << "           n = " << n << '\n';
    cout << "badnessLimit = " << badnessLimit << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/qGV2LdRnYxhU8Eh8